# Пунктуация в устоявшемся выражении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, фразеология

Нужна ли запятая после "так" в этом предложении?
**Пусть всё идёт так, как должно.**

На мой взгляд, запятая разрушает слитность фразы, а мне важно её сохранить.

Comment: Вы можете убрать "так", тогда запятая будет не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю.

Comment: У вас "как дОлжно"?

Comment: Артём, да, "как дОлжно".

Answer (score 1):

В словаре синонимов:
[**так, как должно**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/382118/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA) (наречие) — надлежащим образом; путем; так, как следует.

В этой синтаксической конструкции указательное слово «так» и союз «как» разделяются запятой.
Вот что об этом говорится у Розенталя:
3. Сравнительный оборот с союзом ***как*** выделяется **запятыми** в следующих случаях:
2) если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово (***так**, такой, тот, столь*)...

**Пусть всё идёт так, как должно.**
*Свидетельствовал на суде, проследил за тем, чтобы **всё прошло так, как должно.***
Е. Наду

― Да потому, что вы вырвали отдельное звено из цепи событий, и всё звучит не **так, как должно**. [Юрий Азаров. Подозреваемый (2002)]
И растет вместе с городом из яви ― город горний, где в гости приходят всегда те, кому рад и все происходит **так, как должно**. [Егор Плитченко. Горний город // «Сибирские огни», 2013]

[Сравнительный оборот](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=106)

Answer (score 0):

Нужна запятая.

Между "так как" запятая не ставится только в значении "потому что". В других случаях это явный сравнительный оборот и перед "как" запятая обязательна.

Но без "так" запятая не нужна, поскольку "как должно" можно заменить на "должным образом":
*Пусть всё идёт должным образом.*
*Пусть всё идёт как должно.*